# Tango camera extrinsics

Tags: matlab, google-project-tango, extrinsic-parameters

The extrinsic matrix for camera calibration based on the [MATLAB link](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ug/camera-calibration.html) should be 4x3 matrix (including orientation and translation) means we need 12 elements, however, based on the explanation in [Tango documentation](https://developers.google.com/tango/overview/intrinsics-extrinsics) we only get 3 numbers for translation and 4 numbers for rotation. How can I create that 4x3 matrix with these 7 numbers?

Thanks,
Vahid.

Answer (score 0):

The View Matrix is used to hold these values. It's a 4x4 matrix that allows to manipulate 3D poses (positions + orientations).

You can find more detail about this matrix here :
http://www.3dgep.com/understanding-the-view-matrix/

Note that the Tango java library is based on Rajawali 3D library. You can see the structure of that MatrixX44 here:

https://github.com/Rajawali/Rajawali/blob/master/rajawali/src/main/java/org/rajawali3d/math/Matrix4.java

Especially, the following method shows as how the 7 values are stored.
For an easier reading, you can assume the scale vector is on (1,1,1)

```
public Matrix4 setAll(@NonNull Vector3 position, @NonNull Vector3 scale, @NonNull Quaternion rotation) {
    // Precompute these factors for speed
    final double x2 = rotation.x * rotation.x;
    final double y2 = rotation.y * rotation.y;
    final double z2 = rotation.z * rotation.z;
    final double xy = rotation.x * rotation.y;
    final double xz = rotation.x * rotation.z;
    final double yz = rotation.y * rotation.z;
    final double wx = rotation.w * rotation.x;
    final double wy = rotation.w * rotation.y;
    final double wz = rotation.w * rotation.z;

    // Column 0
    m[M00] = scale.x * (1.0 - 2.0 * (y2 + z2));
    m[M10] = 2.0 * scale.y * (xy - wz);
    m[M20] = 2.0 * scale.z * (xz + wy);
    m[M30] = 0;

    // Column 1
    m[M01] = 2.0 * scale.x * (xy + wz);
    m[M11] = scale.y * (1.0 - 2.0 * (x2 + z2));
    m[M21] = 2.0 * scale.z * (yz - wx);
    m[M31] = 0;

    // Column 2
    m[M02] = 2.0 * scale.x * (xz - wy);
    m[M12] = 2.0 * scale.y * (yz + wx);
    m[M22] = scale.z * (1.0 - 2.0 * (x2 + y2));
    m[M32] = 0;

    // Column 3
    m[M03] = position.x;
    m[M13] = position.y;
    m[M23] = position.z;
    m[M33] = 1.0;
    return this;
}
```